# Controlling the thread in which the Process async Exit handler is executed

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am running a c# console application that spawns another process. I want to be notified when the new process exits. So I register a EventHandler to be aynchronously invoked when process exits. This all works fine and the event handler method gets invoked at the right time. But it seems to be not running in the main thread but a worker thread. Code in the event handler has to update some state in my core classes and I don't want to have thread synchronisation primitives in my code as my application is essentially single-threaded.

I am fairly new to c# and would like to know the best way to approach this. Is there a way to control the thread in which Exited event handler is called. Or a good alternative?

Comment: The event can't hijack your existing thread at a random point in its processing... You need to synchronize. Post code, right now it's not possible to recommend anything.

Comment: Since the event handling is asynchronous, you cannot count on the application to be single-threaded. You have to synchronize.

Comment: Thanks both for confirming the behavior. I agree that invoking Exited event handler in separate thread is logical. I want to know if there is a pattern to deal with these situations.